# Override some options for HOSTCFLAGS when building kernel modules

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

Is that possible to set O0 or O1 when building a specific kernel module? The reason is that I need to use KGDB to debug a specific kernel module which prefer the compile not optimize the code.

The HOSTCFLAGS is set to O2 by default in the Makefile in kernel source's root dir, which makes some kernel debugging not functionally well(e.g.: variable optimized out).

It should not be good if set O0/O1 at the Makefile in root dir, which changes the compile behavior for the whole kernel source.

Comment: `HOSTCFLAGS` variable affects building of *auxiliary programs*, which then used for build kernel and its modules. For change building *kernel module*, you need to change `KBUILD_CFLAGS`, e.g. using `ccflags-y := -O1` in the `Makefile` for given module. Note, that optimization level `O0` may break building process of linux kernel. For more info about building modules see [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Tsyvarev! I have just tried adding "KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Og" to the module's Makefile, and it works:) The question is resovled.